# Class<Cucumber> cannot be resolved to a type in the POM.xml

Tags: cucumber

Below dependencies are added to pom.but still able to see Class cannot be resolved to a type in the POM.xml in the runner class.

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<groupId>FirstBBDApp</groupId>
<artifactId>FirstBBDApp</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>jar</packaging>

<name>FirstBBDApp</name>
<url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
</properties>
```

> Added all dependencies of same version still getting same message

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>info.cukes</groupId>
        <artifactId>cucumber-picocontainer</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.5</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/info.cukes/cucumber-java -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>info.cukes</groupId>
        <artifactId>cucumber-java</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.5</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/info.cukes/cucumber-junit -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>info.cukes</groupId>
        <artifactId>cucumber-junit</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.5</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/info.cukes/cucumber-core -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>info.cukes</groupId>
        <artifactId>cucumber-core</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.5</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>info.cukes</groupId>
        <artifactId>cucumber-jvm</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.5</version>
        <type>pom</type>
    </dependency>
```

> Added all dependencies of same version still getting same message

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>net.masterthought</groupId>
        <artifactId>cucumber-reporting</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>info.cukes</groupId>
        <artifactId>cucumber-jvm-deps</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.3</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/info.cukes/cucumber-html -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>info.cukes</groupId>
        <artifactId>cucumber-html</artifactId>
        <version>0.2.6</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>net.sourceforge.cobertura</groupId>
        <artifactId>cobertura</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>info.cukes</groupId>
        <artifactId>gherkin</artifactId>
        <version>2.12.2</version>
    </dependency>
```

> Added all dependencies of same version still getting same message

```
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/info.cukes/gherkin-jvm-deps -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>info.cukes</groupId>
        <artifactId>gherkin-jvm-deps</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.3</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
        <artifactId>mockito-all</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.2-beta</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/junit/junit -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>4.12</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
        <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
        <version>3.7.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun</groupId>
        <artifactId>tools</artifactId>
        <version>1.6</version>
        <scope>system</scope>
        <systemPath>C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_202\lib\tools.jar</systemPath>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

[Please find dependencies added list](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jUniI.png)

Comment: do not mix versions of cucumber. Use 4.2.0 for cucumber-java, cucumber-junit, cucumber-picocontainer from io.cucumber group. Rest of the necessary cucumber jars will be automatically downloaded.

Comment: After updating to 4.2.0.Still able to see Class<Cucumber> cannot be resolved to a type for "@RunWith(Cucumber.class)" syntax

Comment: What are the imports u have added?

Comment: import org.junit.runner.RunWith;

import cucumber.api.CucumberOptions;
import cucumber.api.junit.Cucumber;

Comment: I have updated all cucumber  version to 1.2.5.Still able to see Class<Cucumber> cannot be resolved to a type error in the runner class

Comment: THe error should come when cucumber.api.junit.Cucumber is not imported. Guess u can try removing all maven dependencies and trying again.

Comment: Tried all possibilities but no luck

Comment: Please find screenshot of dependency list and correct me if iam wrong.

Comment: I think the issue is that the cucumber-junit.jar cannot be found as the import is also red. Have u set the scope of this jar to 'test' in POM? If so u need to remove that. Better solution is to move this runner class to the src/test/java folder where it should be placed.

Comment: After removing the scope.it is working fine.Thanks:)

Answer (score 0):

> By Adding Below dependencies able to resolve the above issue.

```
[<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>FirstBBDApp</groupId>
    <artifactId>FirstBBDApp</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <name>FirstBBDApp</name>
    <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>info.cukes</groupId>
            <artifactId>cucumber-picocontainer</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.5</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/info.cukes/cucumber-java -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>info.cukes</groupId>
            <artifactId>cucumber-java</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.5</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/info.cukes/cucumber-junit -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>info.cukes</groupId>
            <artifactId>cucumber-junit</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.5</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/info.cukes/cucumber-core -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>info.cukes</groupId>
            <artifactId>cucumber-core</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.5</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>info.cukes</groupId>
            <artifactId>cucumber-jvm</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.5</version>
            <type>pom</type>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.masterthought</groupId>
            <artifactId>cucumber-reporting</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>info.cukes</groupId>
            <artifactId>cucumber-jvm-deps</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.3</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/info.cukes/cucumber-html -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>info.cukes</groupId>
            <artifactId>cucumber-html</artifactId>
            <version>0.2.6</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.sourceforge.cobertura</groupId>
            <artifactId>cobertura</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>info.cukes</groupId>
            <artifactId>gherkin</artifactId>
            <version>2.12.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/info.cukes/gherkin-jvm-deps -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>info.cukes</groupId>
            <artifactId>gherkin-jvm-deps</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.3</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
            <artifactId>mockito-all</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.2-beta</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/junit/junit -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.12</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
            <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
            <version>3.7.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/junit/junit-dep -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-dep</artifactId>
            <version>4.11</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.seleniumhq.selenium/selenium-chrome-driver -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
            <artifactId>selenium-chrome-driver</artifactId>
            <version>3.14.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
            <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
            <version>2.8.5</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun</groupId>
            <artifactId>tools</artifactId>
            <version>1.6</version>
            <scope>system</scope>
            <systemPath>C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_202\lib\tools.jar</systemPath>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>][1]
```